# symbol lookup error after updating Qt package

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, archlinux

I recently updated all Qt packages from Pacman(Arch Linux).
After updating I am getting system lookup errors after executing any python code.

```
python: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/iconengines/../../lib/libQt5Svg.so.5: undefined symbol: _ZdlPvm, version Qt_5
```

Comment: How did you install PyQt5? Instead of using pip use the system package: `pacman -S python-pyqt5` or if you want to use pip then create a virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem when I'm installing `ROS` with `manjaro` and run `rosrun rqt_console rqt_console`. I'm sure that I installed PyQt5 correctly with `yay`, So I think it's a problem about dynamic linked library but I'm also confused about details.

My solution works like this:

```sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PAH=/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31572358)